# CSS: make multiple divs float down and then right when end of document is reached

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-float

My code creates a set of `.rectangle` divs that all seem to "float down". I would like them to float down until no more fit in the container and then create one more column to the right and so on. Can I achieve this with css?

I have made a jsfiddle to demonstrate [here](https://jsfiddle.net/JocaPinto/9zowa181/5/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Flexbox` and set `flex-direction: column` on parent and `flex-wrap: wrap`.

```js
for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  $("<div class='rectangle'>" + i + "</div>").appendTo("body")
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.rectangle {
  background: snow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  height: 55px;
  width: 90px;
  margin: 10px;
  /*float property?*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: seems to work, but margins aren't kept the same this way though

Comment: They are just the default of `align-content` is stretch so you can change that.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [column](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-fill) :

https://jsfiddle.net/9zowa181/8/

```js
for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  $("<div class='rectangle'>" + i + "</div>").appendTo("body")
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -moz-column-width: 100px;
  column-width: 100px;
  -moz-column-fill: auto;
  column-fill: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
}

.rectangle {
  background: snow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  height: 55px;
  width: 90px;
  margin: 10px 10px 0;
  display: inline-block;/* avoid boxe to be broken within 2 cols */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this fiddle](http://codepen.io/facundo_larocca/pen/RKKoKa)

The trick is to use a flexbox container and apply `flex-direction: column;` and `flex-wrap: wrap;` like this:

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the div containers to be stacked horizontally until they reach the end of outer div, your code should look like this:

```
.rectangle {
  background: snow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  height: 55px;
  width: 90px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  /*float property?*/
}
```

The *inline-block* value is also supported my most, if not all, browsers.